# Jquery reloads in the MVC Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

**Background** : This is my script file .  I need to replicate the html when the add button in my partial view is clicked.

```
//test.js
$(function () {


console.log("Entered function");


$(".add").click(function () {


    console.log("inside button");
    var $addHtml = $('#Master').html();
    console.log($addHtml.toString());

    $('#Master').append($addHtml);

    });
});
```

I have registered this in my bundle.config

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/EventHandlers").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/test.js"));
```

I have loaded jquery library in the Master layout and

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

My partial view contains

```
 @section Scripts {


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/EventHandlers")
 }
```

and

```
  @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

to load scripts for the corresponding partial views

**Issue :** I have tried with break points. In the debug mode I was able to view the newly added html on the webpage.  After the last step the function reloads again and prints "Entered function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this -Try to use in this way,Example

```
<div class="TargetElements">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
        </div>
 </div>
```

i used this script:

```
(document).ready(function () {
$('.add').click(function () {
    $(".TargetElements:first").clone().insertAfter('.TargetElements:last');
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Register your click event on document ready like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $(".add").click(function () {


       console.log("inside button");
       var $addHtml = $('#Master').html();
       console.log($addHtml.toString());

       $('#Master').append($addHtml);

    });
});
```

this is because you function is also appending in the $("#Master") so it's also running again....
and you do not need to register the click event again and again...

so you will have to register it only once on document ready.

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what is the content of `$('#Master')`.If you are appending your complete partial view then  `Scripts.Render("~/bundles/EventHandlers")` line is the reason why you code again get executed.It will again render the script file.

I will suggest to create container div like below in you partial view ...

```
@section Scripts {


@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/EventHandlers")
 }
    <div id="mainDiv">
       <div id="contentDiv"> ....</div>

    </div>
```

and script like

```
$(".add").click(function () {


    console.log("inside button");
    var $addHtml = $('#contentDiv').html();
    console.log($addHtml.toString());

    $('#Master').append($addHtml);

    });
});
```

Comment: I am not appending the complete partial view . A child div of #master containing a label and a textbox is replicated.